# Compile error: Expected function or variable using Microsoft Word and MS-Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am new to VBA and I wanted to insert few data to Access database using VBA form. The program is starting without issues however when I Insert the datas and submit button it gives

> Expected function or variable

issue. Here what I have tried:

```
Dim name1 As String
Dim surname1 As String
Dim affectedRow As Integer


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

name1 = ism.Text
surname1 = familya.Text

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = con.Open("4IAT")

con.Open = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Pavilion\Documents\IAT.accdb;"

sql = "insert into 4IAT(Name,LastName) values('" & name & "','" & LastName & "')"

con.Execute sql, baza
If baza = 1 Then
MsgBox "barakala"
Else
MsgBox "O'xshamadi "
End If

con.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I would start by adding a space after `4IAT` and `values` and see if that makes a difference, and since one of the field names is `Name` (a bad idea) put brackets around it like `[Name]` to avoid the problem. (or better yet, rename the field so it is not called `Name`)

Comment: Also, where are you setting the values for `name` and `LastName`? Did you mean to use `name1` and `surname1`?

Comment: Remove the `=` from the `Conn.Open` statement, `Open` needs a parameter describing the ConnectionString, not an assignment

Comment: And where are you learning such old techniques? There are many flaws with doing things this way... it is much better practice to use a parameterized query.

Comment: can you post your answer in detail?

Comment: finally solve this issue by just removing recordset

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/expected-function-or-variable

Check the website link, microsoft explains the possible causes of the error.